# как импортировать файлы из разных папок в python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, импорт, модули, python-import

Есть путь до главного файла: `С:\\myapp\app.py`
Так же есть второй файл, нужный для работы: `С:\\myapp\folder\additional_file.py`

Как импортировать файл **`additional_file.py`** в **`app.py`**?

Comment: Сделать folder питоновым пакетом (создать в нём пустой файл `__init__.py`) и потом `from folder import additional_file`

Comment: Можно использовать sys.path[0], но это довольно костыльный вариант

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Довольно простым(но костыльным) выглядит вариант с изменением sys.path[0].

```
import sys
sys.path[0] += r"\\folder"
import additional_file
```

Но я рекомендую вам использовать вариант, предложенный andreymal.